# Changing a foreach loop to a Parallel.ForEach loop

Tags: c#, parallel.foreach

Okay, so here is the basic background.  This program connects to outlook/exchange and parses through all the mail messages to see which are encrypted.  One of the things I would like to do is to use multi-threading to decrease the time it takes to scan through the messages.

Currently the code looks like this:

```
foreach (Object item in folder.Items) {
//Checks for encryption and gets needed info and updates count
}
```

And I would like to utilize the Parallel.ForEach function instead.  I was wondering how I could set it up.  I tried setting up the expression to how it is now, but I get an error stating that the Object type is being used as a variable.  Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Okay, The layout I have been given seems to be correct.  The code looks like this right now:

```
Parallel.ForEach(folder.Items, item =>
{
//does stuff
});
```

I am now getting the following error:

> Error 15  The type arguments for method 
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForEach(System.Collections.Concurrent.OrderablePartitioner,
>   System.Action)'
>   cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments
>   explicitly.

Any ideas?  Thanks for your help guys, it is appreciated.

Okay, I found this site: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2010/03/02/9971804.aspx and it gave me the answer I needed to the error.  I just needed to change the collection to a generic one by making a casting function.

```
static IEnumerable<object> Cast(IEnumerable source)
{
    foreach (object o in source)
        yield return o;
}
```

And then tweak the original to

```
Parallel.ForEach(Cast(folder.Items), item =>
{
//does stuff
});
```

Now it runs without errors.  Hurray.

Comment: Please post your modified code (the code that's giving you the error message).

Comment: After the Edit: It now depends on `folder.Items` and/or `//does stuff`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Something like this:

```
Parallel.For(0, folder.Items.Count - 1, delegate(int i) { 
  object item = folder.Items[i];
});
```

Or with ForEach:

```
Parallel.ForEach(folder.Items, item => {whatever you want to do with item})
```

Note: folder.Items has to be implementing IEnumerable

Comment: +1 for also mentioning the requirement that IEnumerable be implemented.

Comment: @ericj: that follows from the `for(item in Items) ...`

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that this is correct

```
foreach (Object item in folder.Items)
   Process(item);
```

then it changes to

```
Parallel.ForEach (folder.Items, item => Process(item));
```